# New to Java - general JavaDoc issues

Tags: comments, javadoc

General JavaDoc questions here:
How do I know if they are working? I know the format and what they're supposed to be doing, but how do I know if they're doing their job? Should it print out after compiling and running?

Another question - how many JavaDoc comments do I need? My professor really wants us to examine our methods in these commentaries, and explain any variables. Does that mean put it inside the method? or before the method but inside the class? or before the class?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be a tad bit confused as to what JavaDoc actually does.

JavaDoc does not directly impact your program in anyway. JavaDoc is a means of compiling information about your program. Say you get a program and want documentation of what it does in a nice handy format. Common compilers like eclipse have an option to compile an html file full of documentation, just like it shows on the Java API documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
This is all JavaDoc for the most part, it is generated from comments.

My teachers always tell me in regards to comments, you are not commenting for someone who doesn't read code. You don't need comments like....

```
// Prints out hello world
System.out.println("hello world");
```

A programmer knows this functionality already. Programmers are more interested in parameter names and what functions actually do. Example

```
/**
* @param a Number we are dividing into
* @param b Number we are dividing by
* @return Our quotient
*/
public static float divide(int a, int b) {
return (a/b); }
```

Will generate a page like this [image: javadocexample]
Emphasis on the /** at the top, two asterisks denote that below contains JavaDoc. Most IDE's like Eclipse will highlight JavaDoc. [image: syntaxhighlight] 
As you can see the names of the parameters are just a and b, in certain cases it is difficult to label parameter names by what their function may be, so it can save time to use JavaDoc to give a description of them, instead of someone scrolling through your code trying to figure out what the hell they do. You are creating a guide for your program to modify and update it.

JavaDoc is literally a guide to how all your functions, classes, variables work in your program.